# Make selected button titlelabel to be uppercase

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have button with title "Button". After some actions this button gets "selected" status. While it is selected it have different text color that is easy to specify in interface builder.

The problem is that I also want set it's title to be uppercase. Which I don't know how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set Title for Selected State of UIButton from Attribute Inspector.
Please find below image :

[image]

You can also set it programatically.

**Objective-C**

```
[btn setTitle:btn.titleLabel.text.uppercaseString forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

**Swift**

```
 btn.setTitle(btn.titleLabel!.text.uppercaseString, forState: .Selected)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting it from code use

```
var myString = "string"
myString = myString.uppercaseString
button.setTitle(myString, forState: .Selected)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in function for that

```
Button.capitalizedString
```

So you can use it in this way in swift

Let me assume that **abtn** is your **IBOutlet** of **UIButton** and **Button** is **titlelabel** of UIButton.

```
 abtn.setTitle(abtn.titleLabel!.text.uppercaseString, forState: .Selected)
```

as said by [kirsteins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172950/kirsteins)

To capitalize only the **first letter** you can use:

```
nameOfString.replaceRange(nameOfString.startIndex...nameOfString.startIndex, with: String(nameOfString[nameOfString.startIndex]).capitalizedString)
```